# SQL Server 2016 ALTER ASSEMBLY command fails -- not a compatible upgrade

Tags: sql-server, clr, sql-server-2016

I am trying to alter an assembly in SQL Server 2016 with this command:

```
alter assembly mylib from 'F:\Microsoft SQL Server (x86)\mylib.dll'
```

But I am getting this error:

> Alter assembly from 'mylib, version=17.0.0.20501, culture=neutral,
>   publickeytoken=11140e03aaa52226, processorarchitecture=msil' to
>   'mylib, version=0.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=null,
>   processorarchitecture=msil' is not a compatible upgrade.

mylib.dll is compiled with AssemblyVersion, AssemblyFileVersion and AssemblyInformationalVersion all set to "19.17.0.0".  Is it because SQL Server thinks the dll is version 0.0.0.0?

As a test, if I execute these commands:

```
alter assembly mylib1 from 'F:\Microsoft SQL Server (x86)\mylib.dll'
select clr_name from sys.assemblies where name='mylib1'
```

The value of clr_name is:

> idclib1, version=0.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=null,
>   processorarchitecture=msil

So I think I need to specify the version somehow but I don't know how to do that.

This link indicates that version appears as 0.0.0.0 if the assembly is not signed: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32900083--version-incorrectly-showing-as-0-0-0-0-in-sys-as.  I will try signing the assembly and see if that solves the issue.

Help please!

Comment: Do you have other assemblies that reference mylib? They may have `SpecificVersion: true` set in the assembly references of their projects.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I wish I knew how to check for that using T-SQL.

Comment: You'd have to audit the list of registered assemblies from `select * from sys.assemblies` and check the project files for any of them that are yours. On a clean server [database] I'd only expect to see `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue.

First, the assembly needs to be signed with a strong name key file.  The key file does not need to be protected with a password.  This results in an assembly with a publickeytoken.  When the CREATE ASSEMBLY or ALTER ASSEMBLY command is used on the signed assembly, the publickeytoken and version will appear in the clr_name column of the sys.assemblies table.

Second, the same strong name key file that was originally used to sign the assembly must be used to sign the new version of the assembly; if a different key file is used, the ALTER ASSEMBLY command will fail because the publickeytoken will be different.